# How to save .fla files in older Flash IDE format with JSFL?

Tags: flash, scripting, save, jsfl, fla

Since Flash 5.5 by default saves files in 5.5 format that's incompatible in 5.0 editors we need a way to save .fla files in older format with a JSFL script.

Can this be done? How?

Background:
One of our developers installed the Flash IDE 5.5 and ran a modifying script on hundreds of fla files that we have. The changes were ok, but the file save format was not. It automatically saved the 5.0 files in 5.5 format that can not be opened on the 5.0 IDEs.

We could restore files from backups or he could go trough each file manually saving them with the save as dialog.

I'd prefer to find a way to batch save .fla files in older formats like Flash IDE 5.0. JSFL would look close to optimal, but I could not find a way to save the files with specific flash version in mind with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, I don't think that functionality is available in the API.

You might consider running the JSFL on each file, then running a command line script via  FLfile.runCommandLine() to execute an Automator script (if on a mac) or the equivalent (Google it) if on a Windows machine.

You might also want to check out [xJSFL](http://www.xjsfl.com/) (currently in development) which may have functionality for this kind of action in the future.

Comment: Looking forward to see JSFL live ;)

Comment: I think I will go with the macro tool in Windows. Also, xJSFL looks promising. Thanks!